# What directories on the iPhone/iPod Touch are backed up during the iTunes backup process?

Tags: iphone, backup, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPod Touch and have some files I need to save when I do an upgrade. I'd like the backup to be done automatically when sync'ing with iTunes.

Does anyone have a list of what directories are backed up during the iTunes backup process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that `/User/Library/Preferences/` is one directory that is backed up.

Answer (score 1):

This official [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766) document lists all the items that are backed up during the backup and synchronization process. As far as I am aware this list cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure Apple wouldn't let me modify the list, but at least I could put my files inside the folder and kind of "piggyback" my backup along.